# Permanently hide elements after form action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have no idea how to achieve this effect so I'm farming it out in the hopes that someone knows of a standard method or work around that would allow me to hide certain elements after a form submission. I'm trying to hide (3) elements on the dashboard page of my site once the user has submitted a form.

**Elements to hide:**

`.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(2)`, `.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(3)`, `.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(4)`

Once the user has submitted a form the page redirects to a separate success page and then the user clicks a 'Back to Home' button to return to the dashboard. I need to be able to **permanently hide** these (3) elements on a 'per user' basis after the form has been submitted.

**My question is, is this possible and how could I achieve this?**

**Specs:**

Form Submission Method: Post

Classes: `.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(2)`, `.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(3)`, `.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(4)`

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Give us your html at least, though if you wrap those elements in a if statement it works

Comment: @ka_lin unfortunately there's no raw html as such as the tab element itself is generated from a Visual Composer shortcode, so the best I can give you is `[vc_tta_section i_icon_fontawesome="fa fa-home" add_icon="true" title="Home" tab_id="home"]` as an example of a single tab html.

Comment: You are fully reload page, so you need way to store data, that user submit form, and use this data to hide elements. How to store? I think `$_SESSION` good enough. How to hide? Use, for example, jquery, something like `$('.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(2)').hide()` - for all elements.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh thanks, this certainly sounds like the right direction, PHP is a little beyond my knowledge at the moment - please can you confirm if this will be permanent for each user, i.e if they logout and back in will the elements remain hidden? (WP Core CMS)

Comment: "if they logout and back in will the elements remain hidden? (WP Core CMS)" If you will store data in $_SESSION and do not destroy session or delete session data  - YES.

Comment: @VDesign as i understood you question i have solution in php. but as you already said `PHP is a little beyond my knowledge at the moment `.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please upvote. If it answered your question, please mark it accepted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have correctly stored the login status in the session, you can do something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="<?= $_SESSION["logged_in"] ? "logged_in" : "logged_out"?>">
<head>
    <style>
        html.logged_in .vc_tta-tab:nth-child(2),
        html.logged_in .vc_tta-tab:nth-child(3),
        html.logged_in .vc_tta-tab:nth-child(4) {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
...
```

That is, apply a class to an ancestor element and make a rule based on it. If that class doesn't appear, your elements will behave as they normally do.

Comment: Note to OP, you have to use `<?php session_start(); ?>` before you output anything (i.e. before `<!doctype html>`)